# How to find the hacker's code for sending mails from a host in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My server sends emails regularly from the main address to other addresses, the content of these emails is either promotional or threatening, where can I find the plugin that sends these emails?
WordPress is installed in Cpanel for me
[image]

Comment: It does not come from the Elementor plugin

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the distance. You'll need some experts to investigate your server... meanwhile you should take it offline to avoid more damage.

Answer (score 1):

Check the WordPress FAQ page - "[My site was hacked](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/)" to get the general information.

You can use some security plugins like [WordFence](https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) or similar to perform checks of installed themes, plugins and WP core. If no problems are found, maybe you need additional assistance.